# How can I debug a React JS App into Cordova?

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I was trying to integrate a React.js app in Cordova. Everything goes well, but I was not able to debug the app in the simulator. With chrome://inspect it seems like there's no way to do it, because I can only see the "compiled code". Any solution? Thanks

Comment: Did you check this ? https://medium.com/@pshubham/using-react-with-cordova-f235de698cc3

Comment: Yes, I already saw this article. 
In this way the app works, I know, but the problem is: how can I debug the React code? If I open chrome://inspect I just see optimized code impossible to understand and debug

Comment: Nobody has an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another better way, but what do the trick for me is to build react with some custom files that i took from node_modules/react-scripts/
(i do that, to avoid react eject)

You need all the sources map on your app.
React by default, use a certain webpack config, but that config doesn't work in your phone.
By default, react use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCd9n.png)
You can check it on the file node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

What i do, is to build react with the next webpack config
devtool: "eval-source-map",

So you must

1. Copy these files on your source code and adapt some imports (there are some import with relative path) You only need these two files

1. node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js
2. node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

On the first one, modify it to use the second one,
On the second one, add this devtool: "eval-source-map"

2. Create new task on package.json , new custom build to use the script your custom build.js
3. Build with this script, and copy all the source maps with your code, and thats it.
   The debug could crash sometimes, (i try it also with iphone + safari, sometimes works, sometimes don't so you must keep trying)
   On android tend to work in a better way.
   The debug is a little bit slow in compare to the web debug.

I hope this works for you too.

(Sorry for my bad English)